# How can I get the shutter actuation count for Canon EOS 600D (Rebel T3i)?

Tags: canon, canon-600d, shutter-actuations

How can I view the shutter count on an EOS 600D? The EOSInfo software doesn't work for me.

Comment: This may be transient (like all external references) so I'll add it as a comment...  http://youtu.be/EVN6O9GXeKc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shutter count is not included in the EXIF information of images made using EOS cameras such as is the case with some cameras from some other manufacturers. So online solutions where the user uploads a photo from the camera in question or other methods dependent upon a "shutter count" field in the EXIF info do not work with EOS camera.

The shutter count from EOS cameras with DiG!C III and later processors up to cameras released by the end of 2014 make the shutter count available through the remote controlled interface that may be accessed on the camera via a USB connection. The remote control interface may also be accessed via WiFi connection for cameras so equipped with WiFi capability. This includes all DiG!C III, DiG!C 4, and DiG!C 5/5+ cameras. The EOS 7D Mark II is the only DiG!C 6/6+ camera that allows shutter count access via the remote controlled interface. None of the models released since early 2015 with DiG!C 6/6+ or later processors allow the shutter count to be accessed without the proprietary tools used by Canon service centers. For more detailed information about specific models, please see [this page](http://www.direstudio.com/shuttercount/tech-specs/) at [dire studio's website](http://www.direstudio.com/).

Your EOS Rebel T3i/600D falls into the group that allows the remote control application to access the camera's shutter count *for still images taken with the camera*. Live View actuations are not reported via the remote control interface. Only the Canon service centers can extract that info from EOS cameras. (Note: see below for an update)

The aforementioned Dire Studio offers an app called [ShutterCount](http://www.direstudio.com/shuttercount/) that works with compatible Canon EOS cameras listed above. Although it is not free, the cost is very modest. As of December 1, 2016 the [Windows version](http://www.laszlopusztai.net/2015/11/23/shuttercount-for-windows-price-increase/) is $3.99 USD and all other versions are $2.99 USD. I've been using it for about a year and a half and am very happy with it.

### Update

**Dire Studio has released ShutterCount version 3 (currently for Mac or iOS only) that can now read the shutter counts for the cameras excluded above, as well as some other more recent models.** From the updated *FAQ* page as of July 2, 2017:

> Q13 - The shutter count is not displayed for new cameras (5D IV, 5DS/R, 1D X II, etc.)
>
> Update to ShutterCount 3.0 or later on your Mac or iOS device. The Windows version will support these cameras later on.

For a list of all supported cameras, please see the Compatibility List at the [ShutterCount Tech Specs page](http://www.direstudio.com/shuttercount/tech-specs/).

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like Dire Studios is interested in ever updating the Windows version again, due to the high cost of Microsoft licensing. They once had a statement to this effect included in one of the FAQs, but it seems to no longer be there at their site.

As of 22 February, 2018 there has still been no update to the Windows version of *Shutter Count*. In fact, the older version compatible with Windows is no longer offered for sale by Dire Studio.

Dire Studio also now offers [an add-on *Live View Pack*](https://www.direstudio.com/shuttercount/live-view-pack/) to their *Shutter Count* app that allows one to see Live View stills and Live View movie actuations of the shutters in [selected cameras](https://www.direstudio.com/shuttercount/tech-specs/#cameras).

Prior to buying ShutterCount I was using a free app called EOSInfo. However, there are some security concerns floating around the internet about that program's developer so I chose to stop using it.

You can also access the internal shutter count on certain EOS cameras using Magic Lantern. To use [Magic Lantern](http://www.magiclantern.fm/) to access the shutter count you must have one of the cameras listed above for which there is also a version of Magic Lantern available. The original version of magic Lantern was developed for the EOS 5D Mark II and is perhaps the most stable version of ML there is. Since ML is third party software there is [some risk](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/26695/what-are-the-risks-of-using-magic-lantern) in using it.

---

Original answer below. I no longer recommend *EOSinfo* for the reasons explained above. My concerns are primarily related to some of the other applications the same developer has written that has garnered him a very shady to downright hackish reputation.

---

The simplest and easy to use application I have found to view the shutter count on Canon EOS cameras is **ESOinfo**. Please note that this is third party software written by someone other than an official representative of Canon. The "read me" file included in the download lists the following EOS models that are compatible with the program.

> ## Supported Cameras :
>
> Rebel XS/1000D/Kiss F
>   Rebel XSi/450D/Kiss X2
>   Rebel T1i/500D/Kiss X3
>   Rebel T2i/550D/Kiss X4
>   Rebel T3 /1100/Kiss X50
>   Rebel T3i/600D/Kiss X5
>   Rebel T4i/650D/Kiss X6i
>   Rebel T5i/700D/Kiss X7i
>   Rebel SL1/100D/Kiss X7
>   40D - 50D - 60D - 70D
>   7D
>
> 6D
>   5D Mark II
>   5D Mark III
>   1D Mark IV
>   1D X
>   ID C

The Rebel series prior to the 450D/XS (such as the XTi), the xxD series prior to the 40D (such as the 30D), and the xD series prior to the 5D mark II (the original 5D) and the 1D mark IV (such as the 1Ds mark III or the 1D mark III) are not supported.

Comment: Doesn't work for 1000D.

Comment: @dzieciou Which app discussed above are you referencing? The 1000D has the same DiG!C III processor as the 40D and 450D. Anything that works with any of them should work with all of them. I don't own a DiG!C III camera, though.

Comment: I meant EOS Info. Yesterday I've connected it to my PC with Win 10. EOS Utility 2 was able to recognize it. EOS Info couldn't see any camera connected to the PC. I will see how it goes for other cameras like Canon EOS 80D.

Answer (score 0):

As so often with Canon DSLRs, the [Magic Lantern](http://wiki.magiclantern.fm/userguide#shutter_count) alternate firmware provides this feature.