# Can't see the shutter count on my canon 5d mark ii

Tags: canon, dslr

I was recently paid with a canon 5D Mark II for a job I did and I wanted to see the shutter count but I haven't found a place where I can see it online yet. I've looked on many places but I have had no luck. If anyone knows of a website they've tried it'd be great.

Answer (score 5):

There are no online applications of which I am aware that work to give a shutter count for an EOS camera. This is mainly because the shutter count is not included in the EXIF information of images made using EOS cameras such as is the case with some cameras from some other manufacturers.

The shutter count from EOS cameras with DiG!C III and later processors up to cameras released by the end of 2014 make the shutter count available through the remote controlled interface that may be accessed on the camera via a USB connection. The remote control interface may also be accessed via WiFi connection for cameras so equipped with WiFi capability. This includes all DiG!C III, DiG!C 4, and DiG!C 5/5+ cameras. The EOS 7D Mark II is the only DiG!C 6/6+ camera that allows shutter count access via the remote controlled interface officially supported by Canon's SDK (software developers kit). None of the models released since early 2015 with DiG!C 6/6+ or later processors allow the shutter count to be accessed without the proprietary tools used by Canon service centers. For more detailed information about specific models, please see [this page](https://www.direstudio.com/shuttercount/tech-specs/#cameras) at [dire studio's website](http://www.direstudio.com/).

Your EOS 5D Mark II falls into the group that allows the remote control application to access the camera's shutter count *for still images taken with the camera*. Live View actuations are not reported via the remote control interface. Only the Canon service centers can extract that info from EOS cameras.

The aforementioned Dire Studio offers an app called [ShutterCount](http://www.direstudio.com/shuttercount/) that works with compatible Canon EOS cameras listed above. Although it is not free, the cost is very modest. As of December 1, 2016 the [Windows version](http://www.laszlopusztai.net/2015/11/23/shuttercount-for-windows-price-increase/) is $3.99 USD and all other versions are $2.99 USD. I've been using it for about a year and a half and am very happy with it.

### Update

**Dire Studio has released ShutterCount version 3 (currently for Mac or iOS only) that can now read the shutter counts for the cameras excluded above, as well as some other more recent models.** From the updated *FAQ* page as of July 2, 2017:

> Q13 - The shutter count is not displayed for new cameras (5D IV, 5DS/R, 1D X II, etc.)
>
> Update to ShutterCount 3.0 or later on your Mac or iOS device. The Windows version will support these cameras later on.

Dire Studio also now offers an add-on [Live View Pack](https://www.direstudio.com/shuttercount/live-view-pack/) to their [Shutter Count](https://www.direstudio.com/shuttercount/) app that allows one to see Live View stills and Live View movie actuations of the shutters in selected cameras.

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like Dire Studio is interested in ever updating the Windows version again, due to the high cost of Microsoft licensing. They once had a statement to this effect included in one of the FAQs, but it seems to no longer be there at their site.

For a list of all supported cameras, please see the Compatibility List at the [ShutterCount Tech Specs](https://www.direstudio.com/shuttercount/tech-specs/#cameras) page.

As of 22 February, 2018 there has still been no update to the Windows version of *Shutter Count*. In fact, the older version compatible with Windows is no longer offered for sale by Dire Studio.

---

Prior to buying ShutterCount I was using a free app called EOSInfo. However, there are some security concerns floating around the internet about that program's developer so I chose to stop using it.

You can also access the internal shutter count on certain EOS cameras using Magic Lantern. To use [Magic Lantern](http://www.magiclantern.fm/) to access the shutter count you must have one of the cameras for which there is also a version of Magic Lantern available. The original version of magic Lantern was developed for the EOS 5D Mark II and is perhaps the most stable version of ML there is. Since ML is third party software there is [some risk](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/26695/what-are-the-risks-of-using-magic-lantern) in using it.

Comment: A friend of mine tried EOSInfo recently and it looks to be extremely inaccurate IMHO.

Comment: @CrazyDino How so? With what other data was he comparing the results?

Comment: It appeared to be incredibly under what it *should* have been (you get a feel for how often you use the camera, and this guy was a fulltime pro) I think it said only 42000 and we estimated double that. It didnt feel right.

Comment: In other words you just *felt* like it was wrong without any other empirical data? How many other bodies does he use? Even though I use one body most of the time, one of my other bodies gets more clicks because it is the one I use most often for sports.

Comment: We could have counted all the RAW files if we were *that* bothered. But a pro used 5D2 in both studio and wedding situations, had for three years, 42000 clicks? Shooting 1000photos at a wedding week in week out? We measured it as the shutter sounded like it was on the way out. You can claim these comments are BS if you want, but as I said IMHO EOSInfo is inaccurate.

Comment: Just had a quick google, it does appear it can be hit and miss. Sometimes it's very accurate. I'm not sure if this is between models or by bodies.

Comment: @CrazyDino As the answer above points out, Live View actuations are not included in any count provided by accessing the camera's remote controlled interface. So any frames captured using LV won't be included. Most full time wedding shooters I know rarely shoot more than 20-25 weddings a year. And all of them use more than one body.

Comment: Yes. But we both said 'that's not right'. I'm a bit perplexed with this argument. I have said it's my OPINION it's not accurate. Yet you're attempting to proove me wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49438/discussion-between-crazy-dino-and-michael-clark).

Answer (score 0):

The free program EOSinfo.exe does work to check the shutter count.

You can download it here: http://www.astrojargon.net/eosinfo.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

The program is simple and easy to install. I used it to check a mint condition 5D Mark ii with 5500 shutter count. The buyer said what the shutter count was. EOSinfo.exe verified the buyer's claim. I then shot 20 photos and rechecked and it counted them.

I verified the EOSInfo.exe shutter count with Magic Lantern. The default file/folder indexing checked as well.

I noticed Michael Clark's response mentioning security question/info regarding the program... it's freeware, there are risks although no blue screen of death here. :)

Comment: My concerns are primarily related to some of the other applications the same developer has written that has garnered him a very shady  to downright hackish reputation.